# How to map CAPS LOCK key in Vim?

Tags: macvim

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176532/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-in-vim). The accepted answer says it is not possible. Other answers provide a way to do it on linux but I have not check if it worked. I am most interested in knowing if there is a way to do it for mac (although you can post answers for linux as well).

I am only reposting this question here because the other question on SOF is more than five years old. Ideally, I would like to remap to `<ESC>` key to `CAPS LOCK`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `X11` environment, you may achieve what you want
with the following commands:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear lock'
```

which means: from now on, Caps_Lock key isn't anymore a keyboard modifier
and fall back to a normal key

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym Caps_Lock = Escape'
```

which means: get the keycode of `Caps_Lock` and from now on assign it the
keysym of `Escape`.

**Note**: this receipe works on any Unix.

Comment: Is the terminal application not the same as `X11`? I tried putting those commands in my `.vimrc` but it does not recognize it

Comment: I don't know if it works the same on mac but on linux, if you want those commands to be executed automatically by xmodmap, you shouldn't put them in `.vimrc` but in `~/.Xmodmap`. Besides, you don't write the whole command anymore, just what's inside the quotes. For example, instead of putting `xmodmap -e 'clear lock'` in `.Xmodmap`, you just write `clear lock`. Then you restart the computer or you just log out and log in back so that xmodmap reads the file and executes each line it contains.

Comment: @solalito: the commands I gave here aren't internal `vi` commands, but `X11` environment ones. They won't work within `vi` or `Terminal`, because they directly talk to the `X`` server and more precisely to the part which deal with the keyboard managment.

Comment: @solalito: I didn't test it, but from a critical reading of their web server, `Karabiner`: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/ seems to be a correct solution to your problem. If you test it successfully, I suggest you to make here an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The question you posted is still up to date. I've been using the AutoHotkey solution under windows for some years and I'm quite happy with it. I find it useful to also remap the Capslock to Esc under Firefox+Pentadactyl.

As there is no AutoHotkey for mac, you [should look for its alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/?platform=mac).

Answer (score 0):

Steve Losh describes a [Mac specific way](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/#controlescape) in his blog on the crafting a modern Space Cadet.  He also calls out [these](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RemapCapsLock) instructions in his tutorial on Vim.